# sleep-for within while loop is ignored

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write an emacs function that executes a shell command every 5 seconds. However, I can't get the pause to work. Here's what I have:

```
  (while '(test)
    (insert (format "echo hello"))
    (comint-send-input))
    (sleep-for 0 5000)
```

I suspect that the sleep is ignored for reasons related to functional evaluation of Lisp. Any advice on how to get the pause to occur after each command evaluation?

Comment: Maybe `(comint-send-input))` steals last paren from `sleep-for`?

Comment: Consider using `run-with-timer` instead of `sleep-for`.

Comment: Yes, move the paren.  You might also try putting the `sleep-for` before `comint-send-input` instead of after it (dunno).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the issue is with a paren.

Also, I've just tried `sit-for` in `*scratch*` and it performs smoother compared to `sleep-for`.

```
(while 1
  (insert "hello")
  (sit-for 1))
```

But both lock up Emacs, since it's single threaded, so you should be careful with this sort of activity.

Consider using `async` package or something similar instead.